# How to make a interval average on each nested array with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

We are using the size bucket pattern for our datas and we are wondering how could we aggregate the nested array for getting a average every 1, 5 or 10 minutes on this nested array. The structure is as follow:

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62ad1548a7d67adf4943d2f7"),
    "data" : ObjectId("6262a3048cbdacd24c38fbc4"),
    "day" : ISODate("2022-06-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "first" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:59:04.659Z"),
    "last" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:59:59.915Z"),
    "nSamples" : 97,
    "samples" : [ 
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:59:04.659Z"),
            "value" : 8
        }, 
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:59:50.706Z"),
            "value" : 6
        }, 
           ///// MAX 200 Documents in nested array
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:59:59.342Z"),
            "value" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:59:59.915Z"),
            "value" : 12
        }
    ],
    "version" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62ad1548a7d67adf4943d2f7"),
    "data" : ObjectId("62629d178cbdac1e9938fb9e"),
    "day" : ISODate("2022-06-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "first" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:32:04.659Z"),
    "last" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:40:59.915Z"),
    "nSamples" : 97,
    "samples" : [ 
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:32:04.659Z"),
            "value" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:33:50.706Z"),
            "value" : 65
        }, 
           ///// MAX 200 Documents in nested array
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:36:59.342Z"),
            "value" : 45
        }, 
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:40:59.915Z"),
            "value" : 22
        }
    ],
    "version" : 0
}
```

Is it possible to get this structure ?

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62ad1548a7d67adf4943d2f7"),
    "data" : ObjectId("6262a3048cbdacd24c38fbc4"),
    "day" : ISODate("2022-06-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "first" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:59:04.659Z"),
    "last" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:59:59.915Z"),
    "nSamples" : 97,
    "samples" : [ 
        // Less documents
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:56:00.000Z"),
            "value" : 7
        }, 
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:58:00.000Z"),
            "value" : 6
        }, 
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:59:00.000Z"),
            "value" : 4
        }, 
    ],
    "version" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62ad1548a7d67adf4943d2f7"),
    "data" : ObjectId("62629d178cbdac1e9938fb9e"),
    "day" : ISODate("2022-06-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "first" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:59:04.659Z"),
    "last" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:59:59.915Z"),
    "nSamples" : 97,
    "samples" : [ 
// Less docs
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:32:00.000Z"),
            "value" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:33:00.000Z"),
            "value" : 65
        }, 
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:36:00.000Z"),
            "value" : 45
        }, 
        {
            "time" : ISODate("2022-06-17T23:37:00.000Z"),
            "value" : 22
        }
    ],
    "version" : 0
}
```

So far, I first start by a `$match` for selecting values and add a "fromDate" value for searching:

```js
$match: {
  $and: [
    {
      data: {"$in": [ObjectId("62629d178cbdac1e9938fb9e"), ObjectId("62629d178cbdac1e9938fb9f"), ObjectId("62629d178cbdac1e9938fb9d")]} ,
    },
    {
      first: {
        $gte: new Date('2022-07-08T08:10:22.525+00:00')
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

Then by using the `$unwind` aggregate on samples

```json
$unwind: {
  path: "$samples",
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
}
```

And then grouping the values with an interval:

```json
$group: {
  _id: {
    "$toDate": {
        "$subtract": [
          { "$toLong": "$samples.time" },
          { "$mod": [ { "$toLong": "$samples.time" }, 1000 * 60 * 1 ] } // 1 for 1 minute could be replaced by 5, 10 etc...
        ]
      }
  },
  values: {
    $avg: "$samples.value"
  }
}
```

The problem here is that it does not take in consideration that I have multiple "data"... How can I group them by data as well ? Is it possible to keep the same structure and having "less root documents" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to continue your query is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      data: {"$in": [
          ObjectId("62629d178cbdac1e9938fb9e"),
          ObjectId("6262a3048cbdacd24c38fbc4"),
          ObjectId("62629d178cbdac1e9938fb9d")
        ]
      },
      first: {$gte: ISODate("2021-07-08T08:10:22.525+00:00")}
    }
  },
  {$unwind: {path: "$samples", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
  {$group: {
      _id: {
        time: {$toDate: {
            $subtract: [
              {$toLong: "$samples.time"},
              {$mod: [{$toLong: "$samples.time"}, 60000]}
            ]
          }
        },
        orig_id: "$_id"
      },
      values: {$avg: "$samples.value"},
      root: {$first: "$$ROOT"}
    }
  },
  {$sort: {"_id.time": 1}},
  {$group: {_id: "$_id.orig_id",  root: {$first: "$root"},
      samples: {$push: {time: "$_id.time", value: "$values"}}}
  },
  {$set: {"root.samples": "$samples", "root._id": "$_id"}},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$root"}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cHcgP3rQG2Q)